# invoke a jar file(java file) from perl script

Tags: java, perl, jar

Im using eclipse and i need to invoke a jar file from the perl script .

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
my @args = ("java", "-jar", "C:\Users\RajendraPrasadH\eclipseworkspace\ApplicationProtector\target\ApplicationProtector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar");
system(@args);
```

this is the code which i have used in my perl file(echo.pl) to invoke the jar file could anyone please tell me is there any mistake in this "C:\Users\RajendraPrasadH\eclipseworkspace\ApplicationProtector\target\ApplicationProtector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" this is the path where the jar file is present .

Comment: What happens when you put a `use warnings;` at the top of your script like you should be doing?

Comment: Have you tried printing out `@args` to see what it holds?

Comment: @Prasad - is there a reason why you use `"` in `my @args = (....)`?

Comment: @Prasad - try to use `my @args = qw/java -jar C:\Users\RajendraPrasadH\eclipseworkspace\ApplicationProtector\target\ApplicationProtector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/;` instead and see result.

Answer (score 1):

OP's code is perfect *double quotes* misuse case, `use strict` and `use warnings` would alarm about potential problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
my @args = ("java", "-jar", "C:\Users\RajendraPrasadH\eclipseworkspace\ApplicationProtector\target\ApplicationProtector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar");

say for @args;
```

Output

```
Unrecognized escape \R passed through at misuse_double_quote_1.pl line 6.
Unrecognized escape \A passed through at misuse_double_quote_1.pl line 6.
Unrecognized escape \A passed through at misuse_double_quote_1.pl line 6.
Content-Type: text/html

java
-jar
C:SERSRAJENDRAPRASADHCLIPSEWORKSPACEAPPLICATIONPROTECTOR       ARGETAPPLICATIONPROTECTOR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.JAR
```

Perl interpreter performed *interpolation* of double quoted string by expanding *backshash sequences*.

Correct code for `@args = ('...','...','...')`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
my @args = ('java', '-jar', 'C:\Users\RajendraPrasadH\eclipseworkspace\ApplicationProtector\target\ApplicationProtector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar');
say for @args;
```

Output

```
Content-Type: text/html

java
-jar
C:\Users\RajendraPrasadH\eclipseworkspace\ApplicationProtector\target\ApplicationProtector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

More natural way would be to write code as

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

say "Content-Type: text/html\n";
my @args = qw/java -jar C:\Users\RajendraPrasadH\eclipseworkspace\ApplicationProtector\target\ApplicationProtector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/;

say for @args;

system(@args);
```

Output

```
Content-Type: text/html

java
-jar
C:\Users\RajendraPrasadH\eclipseworkspace\ApplicationProtector\target\ApplicationProtector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: "More natural way": depends on the strings. In particular, the path could contain spaces, in which case qw// would not work.